# Is there any actively developed code coverage tool for Flex?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flex4, code-coverage

I'm looking for a way to get code line/branch coverage for my Flex projects. I'm aware of [FlexCover](http://code.google.com/p/flexcover/), which worked fine for me for a long time until now - I'm running into bugs in the compilers which would be fixed in the Flex SDK 4.5. So, is there any other tool to get code coverage information on Flex projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that Flexmojos4 comes with code coverage support:
http://www.sonatype.com/people/2010/04/flex-test-coverage-kept-simple-with-flexmojos/
But it requires Maven build.